# Error : cannot infer type arguments for ProducerRecord<>

Tags: java, spring, kafka-producer-api, endpoint

(I'm sorry if you see some english problem, I'm french !)

I have a problem with a method in a Java Projet using kafka. 
I've got a database of prices and i want to send to kafka a message with all the information of a price when I delete a price.

In my Endpoint.java I've a methode for deleteById(idPrix) :

```
        @DeleteMapping
        @RequestMapping(value ="/delete{idPrix}")

        public Mono<Void> deleteById (@RequestParam(required = true, name = "idPrix") Long idPrix){

       return priceservice.deleteById(idPrix).map( data -> {
                ProducerRecord<String, Price>  producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, idPrix.toString(), data );
                kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
                return null;
           });

           }
```

I got this message : cannot infer type arguments for ProducerRecord<>

I've tried so much different things to make it work but no success. If someone see what's the problem it will be great.

Comment: Well what _is_ the type of `data`? `...map((Price data) -> {...` should do.

Comment: Data is a Price, but there'is still an error when I write (Price data).. I don't know te good way to specify the data type here, I was thinking he will understand with just the map and the producer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this is not too late, just want for future references.
Skip to SECTION 2 for the actual answer, SECTION 1 tries to explain what the error message means in general sense.

So, whenever you come across `cannot infer type arguments for something...` it means you're parsing a wrong type and that obviously won't work.

- SECTION 1:

In your case, let try to understand the snippet piece by piece:
`Mono<Void>`     ---- This means that Mono is a class that accept a generic Type and that means you could parse Void also and if you parse Void, you can't parse a non Void data type, to be clear, let assume your `Mono<Void>` class look like below:

```
public class Mono<T> {
    private boolean status;
    private String message;
    private T data;
    
     //....getter or setter ....
    }
```

So, like you try using it above:
`Mono<Void>` it means you can only do something like below:

```
return Mono<>(true, "Success", /*You can only parse null here*/)
```

If you want to parse Object rather than null there then you will have to change `Mono<Void>` to `Mono<Object>` note "Object" is the Class name of the new Object you want it to return in your case `ProducerRecord Mono<ProducerRecord>`.
If, let assume you don't want to parse anything at all as the third argument, then you can overload the constructor and eliminate the third the argument.

> 

- SECTION 2:

Now facing the main issue, this concept is also applied to `ProducerRecord<String, Price>`:
Does `ProducerRecord<String, Price>` has a constructor that satisfy the implementation above? `new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, idPrix.toString(), data)`;
The constructor should look something like this:

```
public ProducerRecord(Topic topic, String idPrix, Price data){ /*Note Topic might be String in your case just make sure you're parsing the right data-type, and data you're parsing must be of type Price.*/
    }
```

[image]

I sincerely hope I communicated well, fell free to ask me any question.